# Shannon entropy for a vector

Tags: matlab, statistics

I'd like to calculate the Shanon entropy of a vector (psi) over the time period. According to this [reference](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.71.6447&rep=rep1&type=pdf), [image]

I can calculate the entropy for every single element of psi using a loop that computes the entropy at every point. What I wan't to understand is how to set up the probability of psi(tk) lying in a certain bin. and how to set up the total number of bins.
I tried using Matlab's histogram command that will generate the suitable bins (" [N,edges] = histcounts(psi)") but I don't know how to proceed from there. How do I get the probability of each element being in the xth bin?

here is my current code:

```
% get the number of bins
[N,edges] = histcounts(psi)

%// Compute probability
h = hist(psi);
pdf = h / length(psi);

%// Set any entries that are 0 to 1 so that log calculation equals 0.
pdf(pdf == 0) = 1;
e=[];
%// Calculate entropy
for i=1:length(N)
  e(i) = -sum(pdf(i).*log2(pdf(i)));
end
```

any ideas?

Comment: you  should share your code with us and tell us where you get stucked in there. [ask]

Comment: I added my current trial in the question